# Replace string with double quotes + string using regex

Tags: python, regex, double-quotes

I want to replace a string with **(double quotes + string)**. Need to use it into python.

**Input** : `{responseHeader:{status:0,QTime:94}}`

**Output** : `{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":94}}`

Tried `/[^\d\W]+/g` **regex** to get **only string** but don't know how to **replace** it with **(double quotes + string)**.

Comment: Your input data doesn't have single quotes. Is it a JSON data?

Comment: My input doesn't have single quotes. Input data which I am getting as from different source that already not in JSON. That's why I need to convert it into JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
>>> import re
>>> inp = '{responseHeader:{status:0,QTime:94}}'
>>> re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+)',r'"\1"',inp)
'{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":94}}'
```

Comment: @vks Yeah! Damn lucky today! I woke up looking at the mirror

Answer (score 2):

```
([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Try this.Replace by `"\1"`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/18#python

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "{responseHeader:{status:0,QTime:94}}"
subst = "\"\1\""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: @BhargavRao yeah after so many warnings from u ,now i keep that in mind :P